# Why console.log(fibonacci(3)); print undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
let mem = [0, 1, 1];

const fibonacci = (n) => {
    if (n < 2) {
        return mem[n];
    } else if (n == 2) {
        console.log(mem.length-1);
        console.log((mem[mem.length-1]));
        // return (mem[mem.length - 1]);
        return (mem[mem.length-1]); // why this return statement return undefined???
    }
    else {
        mem.push(mem[mem.length - 1] + mem[mem.length - 2]);
        fibonacci(n - 1);
    }
};

console.log(fibonacci(3));
```

Expected output: 2..

Comment: You're missing the `return` on the recursive call.

Comment: **`return`** `fibonacci(n - 1);`

Comment: you mean in the else bracket ? I have tried that.

Comment: Thanks,I know why now,it is because it is just return in the last fibonacci call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

```
let mem = [0, 1, 1];

const fibonacci = (n) => {
    if (n < 2) {
        return mem[n];
    } else if (n == 2) {
        console.log(mem.length-1);
        console.log((mem[mem.length-1]));
        // return (mem[mem.length - 1]);
        return (mem[mem.length-1]); // why this return statement return undefined???
    }
    else {
        mem.push(mem[mem.length - 1] + mem[mem.length - 2]);
        return fibonacci(n - 1);
    }
};

console.log(fibonacci(4));
```

You missed `return` before `fibonacci(n - 1)` in `else`.

Comment: Yes,Thanks you ! Recursive is difficult to me !